# How to embed a YouTube video in Markdown with Redcarpet for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, markdown, redcarpet, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm using [Redcarpet's Markdown parser](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) within Rails 4.1 so that staff can write messages to one another with some formatting. I want them to be able to embed youtube videos too. Maybe something like:

```
Hey, *check out* my video: [VMD-z2Xni8U](youtube)
```

That would output:

Hey, **check out** my video: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VMD-z2Xni8U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Is there any way to do this within Redcarpet's Markdown parser? I assume I would have to write a custom parser of some kind? What's the appropriate way to do this, if there is a way? Is there possibly a standard Markdown way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution seems to be the following. I use `http://youtube/VMD-z2Xni8U` in my Markdown to embed a YouTube video. I then allow autolinking in Redcarpet to autolink this.

```
# /lib/helpers/markdown_renderer_with_special_links.rb
class MarkdownRendererWithSpecialLinks < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def autolink(link, link_type)
    case link_type
      when :url then url_link(link)
      when :email then email_link(link)
    end
  end
  def url_link(link)
    case link
      when /^http:\/\/youtube/ then youtube_link(link)
      else normal_link(link)
    end
  end
  def youtube_link(link)
    parameters_start = link.index('?')
    video_id = link[15..(parameters_start ? parameters_start-1 : -1)]
    "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/#{video_id}?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
  end
  def normal_link(link)
    "<a href=\"#{link}\">#{link}</a>"
  end
  def email_link(email)
    "<a href=\"mailto:#{email}\">#{email}</a>"
  end
end
```

I then create a `markdown` method to use in any view or controller when displaying markdown content:

```
# /app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  require './lib/helpers/markdown_renderer_with_special_links'
  def markdown(content)
    @markdown ||= Redcarpet::Markdown.new(MarkdownRendererWithSpecialLinks, autolink: true, space_after_headers: true, fenced_code_blocks: true)
    @markdown.render(content).html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: http://youtube/VMD-z2Xni8U is not a real youtube link. the youtube links are https://www.youtube.com/v=VMD-z2Xni8U or https://youtu.be/VMD-z2Xni8U or https://www.youtube.com/watch=VMD-z2Xni8U, etc. and your script doesn't work